# Set point size independent of line weight

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following line styles defined in gnuplot:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "red" lw 3 pt 7
set linetype 3 lc rgb "red" lw 1 pt 7
```

It appears as though the points derive part of their size from the lineweight. I'm using these styles inside of a `plot for` loop with `linetype cycle` using the same style for a cspline and the corresponding points, so I don't see any easy way to just define a separate style for the points.

I get results like this:
[image: different size points]

The points respond to `pointsize` but the point in linetype 1 is still slightly larger (presumably from the thicker border).

Is it possible to get the points in these two styles to be the same size?

In response to Miguel's comment, a more complete example of my use case is:

```
filenames = "A B C D"

set linetype 1 lc rgb "blue"        lw 3 pt 7
set linetype 2 lc rgb "red"         lw 3 pt 7
set linetype 3 lc rgb "blue"        lw 1 pt 7
set linetype 4 lc rgb "red"         lw 1 pt 7
set linetype cycle 4

plot for [file in filenames] file.".csv" \
     using 1:2
     title file \
     smooth csplines, \
     for [file in filenames] file.".csv" \
     u 1:2 with points notitle
```

linetypes 5-8 get set by the cycling and are used by the last part of the plotting command. Recommendations on another way to do this would be welcome!

Comment: Indeed, the point's border depends on the linewidth. I think the easiest way is to decrease the point size of linetype 1 a bit (try with `ps 0.9`).

Comment: This fools my eyes - good enough! Make it an answer?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't plot the points and lines independently - could you share the relevant part of your code? If the style is selected with a variable, say `i`, you can define a complementary style with e.g. `(i+100)`, and use `lt 1` for lines and `lt 101` for points (among other possibilities).

Comment: @Miguel Yes, that could also work depending on further requirements: you couldn't have a legend with linespoints sample and you couldn't make use of `linetype cycle`.

Comment: True, I missed the legend part. As for `linetype cycle` you're also right, although it could be circumvented (more or less "uglily").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your very specific case you can set more styles, and do it rather automatically with a `do for` loop (reusing your code):

```
filenames = "A B C D"

do for [i=0:1] {
set linetype (4*i+1) lc rgb "blue"        lw (i == 1 ? 0 : 3) pt 7
set linetype (4*i+2) lc rgb "red"         lw (i == 1 ? 0 : 3) pt 7
set linetype (4*i+3) lc rgb "blue"        lw (i == 1 ? 0 : 1) pt 7
set linetype (4*i+4) lc rgb "red"         lw (i == 1 ? 0 : 1) pt 7
}
set linetype cycle 8

plot for [file in filenames] file.".csv" \
     using 1:2 \
     title file \
     smooth csplines, \
     for [file in filenames] file.".csv" \
     u 1:2 with points notitle
```

With some simple data files:

[image]

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for testing, I got on a machine with pngcairo so posted a figure.

Comment: I had wanted to avoid generating more styles, but why bother when it can be done so elegantly. Thank goodness for ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

For some terminals the size of filled point types depends on the linewidth because they have a border. This is the case for all cairo-based terminals (pdfcairo, pngcairo, wxt and cairolatex), whereas other terminal like svg, postscript, qt don't show this behaviour.

As test case consider

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "red" lw 3 pt 7
set linetype 3 lc rgb "red" lw 1 pt 7

set samples 11
set style function linespoints
plot x lt 1, x + 0.5 lt 3
```

Considering that you want to have the linepoints samples in the legend, you're best choice is to reduce the point size a bit for the line type with the larger linewidth, like

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "red" lw 3 pt 7 ps 0.9
```

The choice of the scaling factor must be determined manually.

Comment: I actually _don't_ want the linespoints style in the legend. Does that change the answer?